# Blob datatype Image not stored in database

Tags: php, mysql

**I am trying to store the image in database using the blob datatype.**

but my program was not storing the image in database.

**code:**

**form.php:**

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 File Name<input type="file" name="image" /><br />
 <input type="submit"  value="Upload" />
</form>
```

**upload.php:**

```
<?php
require_once('connection.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $image  =   addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES[image]['tmp_name']));
    $query  =   "INSERT INTO images ('image') VALUES('".$image."')";
    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    echo "Image id is ".mysql_insert_id();
    echo "Image id is ".mysql_insert_id();
}
?>
```

**please resolve my problem..**

Comment: Use backticks on `image` not single quotes. Any error codes ?

Comment: this site is not on resolving problems. it's on answering questions

Comment: Please don't store images as BLOBs, just don't.

Comment: why?if we store the image as blob type what is the problem. i know performance,any other problems are there,please tell me.

Comment: @cake Filesystem is just enough. Think if you want to convert, scale, crop...or move assets to a different server/storage system [e.g. cloud].

Comment: @  moonwave99 . ok i understood what you said. but my actual question was storing the image in database is fine. its blob or long blob anything is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try to use the below code.**

```
    $image  =   addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
    $query  =   "INSERT INTO images (image) VALUES('".$image."')";
```

i think this time its work fine...

Comment: this is fine for my requirement can give other ones also

Answer (score 3):

A `BLOB` can store `65535 bytes` maximum. If you need more consider using a `MEDIUMBLOB` for `16777215 bytes` or a `LONGBLOB` for `4294967295 bytes`.

Look at [Storage Requirements for String Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/storage-requirements.html#id899830).

My suggestion is use LONGBLOB instead of BLOB.
Hope it will works.

Comment: thank u for your valuable suggestion. but that actual problem is not that. i think any think is fine for me for my requirement.i am giving long blob also not working

Comment: The best approach is to store the image on your filesystem and then reference its location via MySQL. Storing images in MySQL is not recommended. Why put an extra unnecessary strain on your database? All of the large websites (Facebook etc) store their images on a filesystem.

Comment: i know about file system and performance but my client ask blob datatype only. ok i understood what you said. but my actual question was storing the image in database is fine. its blob or long blob anything is fine.

Comment: I hope this vide tutorial will help you for your requirement : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kPGxWaIhLmk .. its a video tutorial showing you how to store images inside a database using the BLOB data type. The showing you how to show that image on a page.

Comment: if any other example also give me please

Comment: Google is the powerful way for getting examples of your requirement ;-) here i will share one more tutorial : http://php-drops.blogspot.in/2011/06/save-image-in-databasemysql-blob.html and from this link you can download its source code : http://php-drops.googlecode.com/files/blob.zip hope it will works..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50880/discussion-between-cake-and-ullas-mohan-v)

Answer (score 0):

Try using backticks on fieldName

```
$image  =   addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this one.this is also another approach for storing the blob image.**

**code:**

```
    $image= $_FILES["image"];
    $image= mysql_real_escape_string("$image");
    $query = "INSERT INTO images (image) VALUES('".$image."')";
    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    echo "Image id is ".mysql_insert_id();
```

Comment: this is also fine for another example for my question